# How do I create a model that is linked to multiple other models at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a contact model but I want to link it to at least 2 models (vendors and clients). If I create a polymorphic association, best I understand is that's still only one connection per contact.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a one-to-many [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). In your example it will be something like:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contactable, polymorphic: true
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts, as: :contactable
end
```

I'm not sure you necessarily need that however. A basic [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) association should do the trick.

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
end

class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts
end
```

Comment: Right. But what if someone is both a vendor and a client? Or an employee of several clients?